# How does the .raw format work (3D models)

Tags: 3d

I want to write a program that takes a 2 variable function as input an outputs a 3D model to be opend in 3d software like blender. I think .raw is the best option because it doesnt care about textures and such things. The only thing i don't understand is how the coordinates should be written in the .raw file...

This is an example:

```
1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 1
```

It is a simple cube exported to raw, ofcourse this is a cube centered at 0,0,0 with sides of 2, but I just don't get the order of the coordinates and the logic of this format.

Anyone who knows anything about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found some article about importing Blender RAW files that may help you.

Basically, a RAW file is a sequence of space-separated coordinates, 3 or 4 to a line:

```
x y z x y z x y z
x y z x y z x y z
```

That, taken in groups of three, represent the triangles in a model. Therefore, if you feed each point into something like `GL_TRIANGLES`, you will get the model. You need to calculate normal data yourself, though.

http://corymathews.com/importing-a-blender-model-into-opengl/

Comment: This link-only answer is advised against by the community. Normally I wouldn't care too much but I also can't tell what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: If you believe this answer is wrong or against community rules feel free to vote to delete it, hovewer I think I helped at least two people with this link.

Comment: Although this is one of the more helpful links I've come across, I'm just having some trouble translating it to Java and making it more dynamic; I don't know how he decided that `[3][4][33]` was the correct size.

Comment: He stated that the format is made of 4-corner polygons, and each corner has `x,y,z` so here are the `3` and `4` values. The `33` is just because his file had `33` polygons. In real code you should make it dynamic with `list` or `vector`. The order of indices is just code-specific, maybe it would be easier to understand if he wrote `[33][4][3]` and changed `for` loops accordingly.